# List stl C++ Struct

Tags: c++, linux, list, stl

I am having a problem with the while loop inserting data into a stl list from text file. Could you please help me understand my errors? Thanks a lot.
Errors are

```
server3.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
server3.cpp:43:11: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
server3.cpp:74:15: error: ‘class std::list<Record>’ has no member named ‘id’
server3.cpp:74:25: error: ‘class std::list<Record>’ has no member named ‘firstName’
server3.cpp:74:42: error: ‘class std::list<Record>’ has no member named ‘lastName’
server3.cpp:75:12: error: ‘class std::list<Record>’ has no member named ‘id’
server3.cpp:76:17: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘hashtable[hash]’
server3.cpp:76:50: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

Code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE =100;/*size of hashTable*/
/*Struct representing the record*/
struct Record
{
     int id;
     char firstName[100];
     char lastName[100];
} rec;


/*Structure representing a single cell*/
class Cell
{
    std:: list<Record> recs;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};

/* The actual hash table */
std::list<Cell> hashtable;



int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{

    ifstream indata; /* indata is like a cin*/
        indata.open("fileName"); /* opens the file*/

    list <Record> rec;/*create an object*/
    int hash;
    while ( !indata.eof() ) /* keep reading until end-of-file*/
    { 
    indata>> rec.id >> rec.firstName >> rec.lastName;
    hash =rec.id % sizeof(hashtable);
    hashtable [hash].listofrecords.push_back (Record);

    }
     indata.close();

   return 0;    



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of them are telling you that `list` doesn't have no members, because you try to do

```
indata>> rec.id >> rec.firstName >> rec.lastName;
```

but `rec` is a list, not a `Record`.

```
hashtable[hash]
```

is also illegal (see the interface for `std::list`, and `Record` is a type, and you can't insert a type in a container, you can only insert objects:

```
...push_back (Record);
```

is illegal.

The code doesn't have just the occasional error we all make from time to time, but is **fundamentally flawed**. I suggest you start learning C++ (if that's what you're doing) from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: what does it mean? Thanks.

Comment: @NatashaLevesque it means you need to start learning C++ from a reliable book.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are creating a collection of records, but this means that you need to access an element of the collection before accessing the fields of the records contained there.

Here's a reference on using the list type:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three major problems with this line alone.

```
 hashtable [hash].listofrecords.push_back (Record);
```

1. `std::list` doesn't have an `operator[]` so you can't use the `[hash]` subscripting.
2. No place in your program have you defined what `listofrecords` means.
3. You are trying to `push_back` a *type* named `Record` where an object is required.

Please find a good C++ book to get started with: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)